# Firebase is not pulling up img with getDownloadURL

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I currently have this item (one as an example but there are more)

```
Luke-Muñiz.jpg
```

I see it in `gs://example.com/images/`
then I make a call to firebase like so:

```
props.firebase.storageRef(`images/${props.data.profilePic}`).getDownloadURL().then(url => {
      setImgRef(url);
```

When I do the above I get a 403 error.

```
FirebaseStorageError {code_: "storage/object-not-found", message_: "Firebase Storage: Object 'images/Luke-Muñiz.jpg' does not exist.", serverResponse_: "{↵  "error": {↵    "code": 404,↵    "message": "No…not get object",↵    "status": "GET_OBJECT"↵  }↵}", name_: "FirebaseError"}
```

Then of course GET url gives a 404

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/example-bda7b.appspot.com/o/images%2FLuke-Mu%C3%B1iz.jpg
```

My rules for storage are:

```
1
rules_version = '2';
2
service firebase.storage {
3
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
4
    match /{allPaths=**} {
5
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
6
    }
7
  }
8
}
9
​
```

I can confirm I'm logged in since I can view some of the images.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That error means the file you're trying to download isn't in the bucket, or you've got the wrong name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe that ñ is confusing (see snippet). Try to `encodeURI` your `props.data.profilePic`.

```js
const name = 'Muñiz'; // copied from question
const encoded = encodeURI(name);
console.log(encoded);
const decoded = decodeURI(encoded);
console.log(decoded);
const yours = decodeURI('Mu%C3%B1iz'); // copied from question
console.log(yours);
```